# How to access specific object from the database in Django to display it in the webpage?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, web

I am trying to display the title and description from an SQLite database in Django?
I have all the data from my database and from views file I have returned it as `context`.
Here's the `model.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        posts = posts.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = search_query) |
            Q(content__icontains = search_query)
        )

    context={
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request,'blog/home.html', context)
```

And here the HTML code:-

```
    {% for post in posts %}
      <div class="slide-description">
          <label class="slide-0">
              <h1 class="text-slide">{{Here i want to print the title 1}}</h1>
              <h5>{{Here I want to print the content 1}}</h5>
              <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
          </label>
          <label class="slide-1">
              <h1 class="text-slide">{{Here i want to print the title 2}}</h1>
              <h5>{{Here I want to print the content 2}}</h5>
              <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
          </label>
          <label class="slide-2">
              <h1 class="text-slide">{{Here i want to print the title 3}}</h1>
              <h5>{{Here I want to print the content 3}}</h5>
              <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
          </label>
          <label class="slide-3">
              <h1 class="text-slide">{{Here i want to print the title 4}}</h1>
              <h5>{{Here I want to print the content 4}}</h5>
              <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
          </label>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Is there any way to get my job done i.e., display one title at a time or like what I am trying to say is, is there something like: `post.title[1]`, `post.title[2]`,.... or anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop through the posts.

```
      <div class="slide-description">
         {% for post in posts %}
          <label class="slide-0">
              <h1 class="text-slide">{{post["title"]}}</h1>
              <h5>{{post["content"]}}</h5>
              <a href="/" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
          </label>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

Comment: That's not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get that object with the specific title or content, like this:

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.get(title='that title you want to use')
    posts2 = Post.objects.get(title='that second title you want to use')
    and...
    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        posts = posts.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = search_query) |
            Q(content__icontains = search_query)
            )

     context={
        'posts': posts
         }
     return render(request,'blog/home.html', context)
```